# How to hide back up files (xxxxx~)

Tags: kde

In KDE, it always displays the backup files with ~.
Is there any method to hide these files?

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about the backup files generated by Kate and KWrite, I always find it easier to just configure them to put a dot in front of the backup files so they're hidden by all file managers and `ls`.

To do so from go to *Settings* and *Configure Kate* in Kate or *Configure Editor* in KWrite.  Then select *Open/Save* on the left and go to the *Advanced* tab.  In the *Prefix* box, just type a period (`.`).  Alternatively, you can turn backup files completely off by making sure the *Local files* and *Remote files* checkboxes are not checked.

[image: Kate configuration]

Other editors have similar configuration options.

Comment: What theme are you using? :)

Comment: @Whirlwin:  It's just Oxygen, with the *Obsidian Coast* color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/448635-fyi-hiding-files-folders-kde-4-x-later.html